# Proper Systax/Use for PHP File Upload

Tags: php

I'm using this system for our school project. However, I can't find the answer to my current problem.

The program flow is this:

- The registered user will upload a file with texts on the form
- The registered file will appear on the global market (own description)

The problems:

- The images can't be uploaded
- I used simple file upload for this, but I can't find a way to use it properly

Here was my code:

```
<table border=1>
    <th colspan=2>Sell your Item! </th>
<tr>
    <td colspan=2><input type=file id=file>Product Name:<input type=text name=productName>
```

Upload Form:

```
 <?php

        if (ISSET($_GET['submit']))
            {

            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],"images/".$_FILES['image']["name"]."-owner-".$_SESSION['username']."-firstname-".$_SESSION['f_name'])
             $showimage = "images/".$_FILES['image']["name"];
                include ("dbconnect.php");

                    $a = $_SESSION['username'];
                    $b = $_GET['info'];
                    $d = $_GET['productName'];
                    $e = $_GET['category'];
                    $f = $_GET['price'];




                    $query = "INSERT INTO `products`(`product_name`,`product_category`,`product_info`,`product_owner`,`product_price`) VALUES ('$d','$e','$b','$a','$f')";
                    $result = $con->query($query);

                echo "<font size=5px color=red><center>Product successfully posted on the online market</center></font>";
            }

    ?>
```

I used a simple image/file upload earlier and it worked now, I have to use it for my project.

And for the display of the images on a resultIFrame I used this code below:

```
 <?php
   if(isset($_GET['search']))
{
    $a=$_GET['searchbar'];
    include("dbconnect.php");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_name LIKE '%$a%'";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $bilang=mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if($bilang==0)
            {
            print "<font color=red>No existing product";
            }
        else 
            {
            while ($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {   
                    $a=$rows['product_name'];
                    $b=$rows['product_category'];
                    $c=$rows['product_info'];
                    $d=$rows['product_owner'];
                    $e=$rows['product_price'];
                    $_SESSION['product_name']=$a;

                    print "<table border=1>
                        <tr>
                            <td height=250px width=150px>

                                <center></br><img src='$product_image_path'></br>
                                <center><b>$a</b>
                                    </br>$c
                                    </br>$b
                                </br><b>$e</b>
                                </br>$d
                                </br><center><a href='about.php?product_name=$a&product_category=$b&product_info=$c&product_owner=$d'>
                                Learn more...</a>
                            </td>


                            ";
                }   
        //print "<tr><td colspan=6><center>Total Record/s found : <b>$bilang</b></center></table>";
            }
}
```

?>

Comment: check if got anything in `$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']` ?

Comment: you are saving it directly from the post data. What if data is not posted and $_FILES is empty ?

Comment: You're not doing any error checking at all. If something goes wrong you have no way to debug it. Read the PHP manual on [Handling File Uploads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php)

Comment: Do you have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` inside `<form ... >` tag? eg. `<form name="formname" action="somefile.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: and also add name attribute in `<input type=file id=file>` so it becomes `<input type=file id=file name=image>`

Answer (score 1):

You have a written a bad code, you didnt store the filepath of the uploaded file. Without it you wont be able to view the file

HTML

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="youfilename.php">
.........
.....
. 
<input type="file" name="image">
.........
.......
.
</form>
```

Code

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && (!empty($_FILES["image"]) && $_FILES['image']['error'] == 0))
{
$filename = "img-owner-" . $_SESSION['username'] . "-firstname-" . $_SESSION['f_name'] . $_FILES['image']["name"];
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], 'img/' . $filename))
    {
    include ("dbconnect.php");

    $a = $_SESSION['username'];
    $b = $_POST['info'];
    $d = $_POST['productName'];
    $e = $_POST['category'];
    $f = $_POST['price'];
    $query = "INSERT INTO products(product_name,product_category,product_info,product_owner,product_price,product_image_path)
     VALUES ('$d','$e','$b','$a','$f','$filename')";
    $result = $con->query($query);
    if ($result)
        {
        echo "<font size=5px color=red><center>Product successfully posted on the online market</center></font>";
        }
    }
}


else
    {
    echo "Your error message";
    }
```

Also alter your products table and add another column `product_image_path` or any other relevant name you can think of.

To view the image just extract the values from the table and use this code

```
<?php
       if(isset($_GET['search']))
    {
        $a=$_GET['searchbar'];
        include("dbconnect.php");
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_name LIKE '%$a%'";
        $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        $bilang=mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if($bilang==0)
                {
                print "<font color=red>No existing product";
                }
            else 
                {
                while ($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                    {   
                        $a=$rows['product_name'];
                        $b=$rows['product_category'];
                        $c=$rows['product_info'];
                        $d=$rows['product_owner'];
                        $e=$rows['product_price'];
                        $product_image_path=$row['product_image_path'];
                        $_SESSION['product_name']=$a;

                        print "<table border=1>
                            <tr>
                                <td height=250px width=150px>

                                    <center></br><img src='$product_image_path'></br>
                                    <center><b>$a</b>
                                        </br>$c
                                        </br>$b
                                    </br><b>$e</b>
                                    </br>$d
                                    </br><center><a href='about.php?product_name=$a&product_category=$b&product_info=$c&product_owner=$d'>
                                    Learn more...</a>
                                </td>


                                ";
                    }   
            //print "<tr><td colspan=6><center>Total Record/s found : <b>$bilang</b></center></table>";
                }
    ?>
```

Comment: Oops @Lepanto thanks for editing i had forgotten to check his variable

Comment: I got this message: `syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Buy_And_Sell\productsell.php on line 88`

Comment: If you had used above code, it is missing close brackets in `if ((move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],'img/'.$filename)`. correct it to `if ((move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],'img/'.$filename)))`

Comment: The values we're not inserting to the db. :( Anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: did you add a column in the `products` table tht will store the path?Also i have removed a single quote from `$f` as it is of type int i guess

Comment: The forms doesn't add anything on my Database :( @Tabby Yeah, I added those. `$f` is a Varchar that's why I enclosed it with '' :)

Comment: did you get any error? also before running the `if` condition to check if submit is set do a `print_r($_POST)` and tell me the output

Comment: Yes. The values aren't inserting in the db :(